# Null User Object Next-Auth MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, next-auth

Hi im currently trying next auth for our project and I have encountered a problem with the session user object. Im using MongoDB for the database, and everything is fine, I can do basic tasks such as login, register, and logout. However, the user object returned by the credentials provider authorize function is empty and thus, I cannot access user information.

connect():

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config()

const mongoUrl: any = process.env.MONGO_URL;

const connect = async () => {
    if(mongoose.connections[0].readyState) return;

    try {
        await mongoose.connect(mongoUrl);
        console.log("Connection Successful");
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error("Error With Database Connection: " + err);
    }
}

export default connect;
```

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import User from "@/models/user.model";
import connect from "@/utils/db.config";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs");

export const authOptions: any = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: "credentials",
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                login_name: { label: "Login Name", type: "text" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials: any) {
                await connect();
                try {
                    const userData = await User.findOne({ login_name: credentials.login_name });
                    if (userData) {
                        const isPasswordMatch = await bcryptjs.compare(credentials.password, userData.password);
                        if (isPasswordMatch) {
                            return userData;
                        }
                    }
                    return null; // Return null if user is not found or password doesn't match
                } catch (err: any) {
                    throw new Error(err.message);
                }
            }
        })
    ],
};

export const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I tried this solution from https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/2762, but when trying to return the predefined properties alongside additional information from the database, the additional properties are not included. Is there any way to solve this? Or is this next-auth's protection or what not? Still new to this so anything will help.